# C# Math Not Accurate?

Tags: c#, rotatetransform

I have two variables: `counter` and `frequency`. I am using these two variables as such:

```
counter = counter >= frequency ? 0 : counter + 1;
```

As you can see, the counter counts up, until the point it matches the frequency, and then it resets to 0. At the moment, `frequency` is set to `100`. So the counter should reach 99, and then reset to 0.

I am using this counter to rotate an image at a rate of 100 times a second:

```
private int counter = 0;
private int frequency = 100;
private DispatcherTimer dispatch = new DispatcherTimer();

public Timer()
{
    this.dispatch.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000 / frequency);
    this.dispatch.Tick += new EventHandler(updateTimer);
    this.dispatch.Start();
}

private void updateTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    counter = counter >= frequency ? 0 : counter + 1;
    saveImage.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(counter * 3.6);
}
```

The script will rotate the image around a 360 degree plane. Since frequency is set to 100, it will go the full 360 degrees, since 100 * 3.6 is 360. This works great if the frequency is set to 100. However, if I change the frequency, it may not go the full 360 degrees; or it may even go more than 360 degrees.

A simple fix to this would be to change the rotation math to the following:

```
    saveImage.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(counter * (360 / frequency));
```

However, doing this in actuality produces an odd result. The image never reaches the full 360 degree turn; and instead only reaches 300 degrees, before it eventually resets to 0. What is wrong with my math here?

Comment: Why don't you add a `Debug.WriteLine(counter * 3.6)` and see for yourself?

Comment: `c * (360 /f)` will use integer operations. `360/100 -> 3.6 -> 3`

Comment: Related issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840428/how-to-be-warned-about-potential-arithmetic-errors-due-to-type-conversion

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may have rounding issues. Be aware that if you want floating point results you need to do floating point math. In your code, you're mixing `int`s and `double`s, which may result in (unexpected) integer divisions. For example `360 / frequency` will not result in a floating point number, as both frequency and `360` are `int`s (for example 360 / 100 == 3!!).

Try changing your code to use floating point operations consistently as follows:

```
private double counter = 0.0;
private double frequency = 100.0;
private DispatcherTimer dispatch = new DispatcherTimer();

public Timer()
{
    // You may want integer division in this line to get full milliseconds
    this.dispatch.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds((int)(1000.0 / frequency));
    this.dispatch.Tick += new EventHandler(updateTimer);
    this.dispatch.Start();
}

private void updateTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    counter = counter >= frequency ? 0.0 : counter + 1.0;
    saveImage.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(counter * 3.6);
}
```

And the last example you gave should read:

```
saveImage.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(counter * (360.0 / frequency));
```

with `counter` and `frequency` being `double`s.

---

EDIT: It would suffice to change the last line to

```
saveImage.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(counter * (360.0 / frequency));
```

and leave the variables as `int`. Your last line in `updateTimer` doesn't work as `3.6` is hardcoded, but depending on frequency `counter * 3.6` may not reach/be greater than 360°.

Example:

```
frequency = 50
counter = 49
counter * 3.6 = 176.4

frequency = 150
counter = 149
counter * 3.6 = 536.4
```

So you *always* need to calculate the degrees to rotate in every step according to `frequency` and not hardcode them as if `frequency` was 100.

Comment: Hmm... I need integer math for other parts of my code. But couldn't I just change `360` to `360.0` in my existing code and call it a day?

Comment: You could do that, as `int / double == double` and `int * double== double`. However, keep this in mind as a problem you may encounter again! `int / int != double`!