# How to enforce never divide two `int`

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, roslyn, editorconfig

Is there a way to enforce never divide (`/`) two `int` in C# at compile-time/VS/editorconfig/etc?

e.g.

```cs
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
var c = a / b; // NO!
var d = (double)a / b; // OK
```

Thanks!

Context: I am working on a legacy code and it was dividing two `int` values that rounded towards `0`. I suspect there are other places that the same scenario exists. Instead of enforcing, I think it will still be very beneficial to analyze the code to show all occurrences of division of `int` and proactively fix the issue before it happens again.

Comment: I can't imagine you actually want to. Integer division is valid. Yes you have to understand what it does, but that goes for every line of code you write.

Comment: I agree. I guess at least to show all occurrences of division of int? I'm working on a legacy project and we just had a bug because of this. I suspect there may be other places that this same bug exists.

Comment: I'm sure you could write an analyzer to identify that scenario, but this is what units tests are for. Is your code designed to be testable?

Comment: I'm just curious... someone divided an integer and that caused a bug? Can you explain that?

Comment: Unfortunately, most parts of the legacy code are **not** testable.

Comment: @JohnWu on the example above, `c` is still an `int` and is actually `0`. See also [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#integer-division)

Comment: @JanPaoloGo just stop using `int` then.

Comment: You can certainly write a [Roslyn analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix) that detects integer division and then crank the message it gives up to an error (or at least promise to never ignore the warnings), though  there is a learning curve associated with that. You're probably much better off simply searching for all occurrences of " / " in your code (a slash surrounded by spaces), i.e., find all uses of division and inspect them manually. Most code bases do not heavily use division.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to be warned about potential arithmetic errors due to type conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840428/how-to-be-warned-about-potential-arithmetic-errors-due-to-type-conversion)

Comment: Also, *all* code is testable (trust me on this); it's just a matter of how difficult it is to set up. Things like [Microsoft Fakes](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/test/isolating-code-under-test-with-microsoft-fakes) can be a huge help in isolating code without changing it, then writing tests to ensure the semantics are preserved, then refactoring it with the tests as a backstop. Things like LocalDB can be used for databases. Takes a lot of effort, sure, but that still beats staying with code that has no effective tests forever.

Comment: @JohnWu Thanks for finding the dup!

Comment: @JeroenMostert finding " / " is a good idea. I guess what I meant was that most parts of the legacy code are not *easily* testable.